# Admin Logged In Notify Globaly

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I have built a chat plugin in which I want to show chat status that admin is online somewhere or not. I want to show "`Admin is logged in`" when admin is logged in somewhere and "`admin is offline`" when admin is offline somewhere. How can i manage that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an entry in database when admin log in and can remove or update that entry when user logout.

there might be a situation when admin leave website without logged out for that you can set time for auto logout.
I don't think there is a way to find out if admin is login or not from somewhere in wordpress.
you just check if login user is admin or not.